# What is a good way to relink a database using greendao?

Tags: android, database, greendao

I am somewhat of a noobie at developing Android applications and at using databases in general so please keep that in mind.

The setting: I am building an app that receives jsondata from a server, this is parsed with gson, made into objects of the classes generated by greendao and then inserted in the database.

My problem: The objects are inserted without any local link hierarchy. At the moment, the parent id's are still stored within the objects and can thus be set by manually going through all objects. My approach looks like this:

```
//Relevant part of the generator file
user = schema.addEntity("User");
user.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
user.addLongProperty("serverId");

area = schema.addEntity("Area");
area.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
userLinkId = area.addLongProperty("_parent").getProperty();
area.addLongProperty("serverId");
area.addLongProperty("serverParentId");

area.addToOne(user, userLinkId);
user.addToMany(area, userLinkId);

//Relevant part of the datainsertion    
SyncObject theobject = gson.fromJson(jo.getAsJsonObject("new"),SyncObject.class);
app.getSession().getAreaDao().insertInTx(theobject.areas);

QueryBuilder<User> qbu = app.getSession().getUserDao().queryBuilder();
List<Area> areas = qba.list();
    for (Area a : areas) {
        Long userServerId = a.getServerParentId();          
        List<User> users = qbu.where(UserDao.Properties.ServerId.eq(userServerId)).list();
        a.set_parent(user.getId());
    }
```

This works, but is it really the right approach?